# Android OS Bug in User Preference- datatype

Tags: android, android-preferences, type-conversion

I have a set of values defined in preference.xml:

```
  <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="19999999999"
            android:key="@string/phone_number"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:summary="Test Number"
            android:title="Phone" />
```

For some reasons, the OS thinks "19999999999" is an integer(int type) and caps it to 2^31. So I end up seeing something like: **672647167**

19999999999 : **10010101000000101111100011111111111**

Removing the first four binary numbers, I get the following that matches with what Android OS shows.

672647167 : **101000000101111100011111111111**

Is there a workaround?

Comment: android:defaultValue="@string/default_value" should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like `android:hint="@string/PhoneNumberDefault"` and put your phone number in the strings resource. Should have the desired effect.